Create k nodes evenly spaced below another node
I have a node MyFigure that contains an image of a grid which has k elements evenly spaced.
I would like to create k nodes below MyFigure such as each node is aligned with an element of the image.
Something like this:

Where the top black block is MyFigure and the four block below are the text node. It should be noted that MyFigure contains a single jpg image (and not four) composed of k part evenly spaced.
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \def\myspace{???} %width of MyFigure divided by 8
      \node (MyFigure) [inner sep=0,outer sep=0] {{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{myimage.jpg}}};
      
      \node (node1) [below= of MyFigure.west, xshift=(1*\myspace)] {\LARGE \textbf{Foo}};
      \node (node2) [below= of MyFigure.west, xshift=(3*\myspace)] {\LARGE \textbf{Bar}};
      \node (node3) [below= of MyFigure.west, xshift=(5*\myspace)] {\LARGE \textbf{FooBar}};
      \node (node4) [below= of MyFigure.west, xshift=(7*\myspace)] {\LARGE \textbf{FooFooBar}};
  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The idea would be to set \myspace to the width of MyFigure divided by 2k but I am struggling to get only the width of the image.
I also tried something like that \draw let \p1 = {$(MyFigure.east)!0.125!(MyFigure.west)$} in \node (node1) [below= of MyFigure.west, xshift= \x1] {\LARGE \textbf{Foo}}; but it is not working.

Please provide a sketch what result you expect. Be aware, that we haven't your image so we don't know anything about image's segments.

Have a look at matrix in Tikz, e.g. in the tutorials and with more details here https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices#autosec-3781

I added a drawing of the expected result.

\newlength\mylen\settowidth\mylen{\includegraphics[...]{...}}\divide\mylen8\edef\myspace{\the\mylen}

The calc library's let … in syntax can be used to find out the width of the graphics (well, it actually determines the width of the node).
Then it's just a matter of where to use this width (accessible by \x0).
The \createKnodesUnderImage{<list>} determines the number of entries in the <list> and evaluated the needed ratio for the width on its own.
Some values are hard-coded, here the distance between image and the nodes (5mm) as well as the white space around the nodes (2mm on each side).
This can be adjusted or be parametrized as well, of course.
Code
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{tight nodes/.style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt}}
\newcommand*\createKnodesUnderImage[1]{%
  \setcounter{pgf@counta}{0}\foreach\i in{#1}{\stepcounter{pgf@counta}}
  \pgfmathreciprocal{\value{pgf@counta}}\let\knodesscale\pgfmathresult
  \path let \p0=($(image.east)-(image.west)$) in [
    shift=(image.south west), yshift=+-5mm, node font=\bfseries,
    minimum width=\knodesscale*\x0-2mm, anchor=north
  ] foreach[count=\i from 0]\t in{#1}{
    node[draw, xshift=\knodesscale*\i.5*\x0]{\t}};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[tight nodes](image){\includegraphics{example-image}};
\createKnodesUnderImage{Foo, Bar, FooBar, FooFooBar}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


I hope that following image is sufficient close to what you after:

MWE (Minimal Working Example), which produce it, I wrote from scratch :-). In it I use chains, fit and positioning libraries:
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 4mm,
  start chain = going right,
F/.style = {draw, inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=1mm, fit=#1},
M/.style = {text width=18mm, inner sep=0pt, on chain},
N/.style = {draw, text width=21mm, minimum size=2ex,
            font=\large\sffamily, inner xsep=0pt, align=center}
                    ]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\node (n11) [M] {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node (n12) [M] {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node (n13) [M] {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
\node (n14) [M] {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};
      
\node (n21) [N, below=of n11]   {Foo};
\node (n22) [N, below=of n12]   {Bar};
\node (n23) [N, below=of n13]   {FooBar};
\node (n24) [N, below=of n14]   {FooFooBar};

   \node    [F= (n21.west |- n11) (n11) (n24.east |- n14)] {};
   \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{document}

